# Braintree Transaction, multiple lineItems, PHP

Tags: php, braintree

I am trying to include multiple *lineItems* in a **Braintree** transaction for each product in the basket.

The transaction below is successful and it works as expected, only one item is added as a lineItem.

```php
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'orderId' => $hash,
    'amount' => $this->basket->subTotal() + $this->basket->delivery(),
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $request->getParam('payment_method_nonce'),
    'shippingAmount' => $this->basket->delivery(),
    'discountAmount' => '0',
    'shipsFromPostalCode' => '7008',
    'taxExempt' => true,
    'purchaseOrderNumber' => $hash1,
    'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => true,
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'firstName' => $request->getParam('name'),
        'email' => $request->getParam('email'),
    ],
    'shipping' => [
        'firstName' => $request->getParam('name'),
        'streetAddress' => $request->getParam('address1'),
        'locality' => $request->getParam('city'),
        'postalCode' => $request->getParam('postal_code'),
        'countryCodeAlpha3' => 'AUS',
    ],
    'lineItems' => [
        [
            'quantity' => $product->quantity, 
            'name' => $product->title, 
            'kind' => 'debit', 
            'unitAmount' => $product->price, 
            'totalAmount' => $product->price * $product->quantity
        ],
    ]
]);
```

However, when I try to include all products in the basket like the following

```php
$basketProducts = $this->basket->all();

if($basketProducts){
    $lineItems = '';
foreach ($basketProducts as $product){
    $lineItems .= <<<EOD
    [
        'quantity' => $product->quantity, 
        'name' => $product->title, 
        'kind' => 'debit', 
        'unitAmount' => $product->price, 
        'totalAmount' => $product->price * $product->quantity
    ],
EOD;
}
}

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'orderId' => $hash,
    'amount' => $this->basket->subTotal() + $this->basket->delivery(),
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $request->getParam('payment_method_nonce'),
    'shippingAmount' => $this->basket->delivery(),
    'discountAmount' => '0',
    'shipsFromPostalCode' => '7008',
    'taxExempt' => true,
    'purchaseOrderNumber' => $hash1,
    'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => true,
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'firstName' => $request->getParam('name'),
        'email' => $request->getParam('email'),
    ],
    'shipping' => [
        'firstName' => $request->getParam('name'),
        'streetAddress' => $request->getParam('address1'),
        'locality' => $request->getParam('city'),
        'postalCode' => $request->getParam('postal_code'),
        'countryCodeAlpha3' => 'AUS',
    ],
    'lineItems' => [
        $lineItems
    ]
]);
```

I get this error message:

> Type: InvalidArgumentException
>   Message: invalid keys: lineItems[   [ 'quantity' => 1, 'name' => Apricot Chicken, 'kind' => 'debit', 'unitAmount' => 9.8, 'totalAmount' => 9.8 * 1 ],]
>   File: C:\wamp64\www\vendor\braintree\braintree_php\lib\Braintree\Util.php
>   Line: 396

So it seems like it's pulling the right data from that variable, it's just Braintree detecting it as invalid.
Am I missing something? Any help would be much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a string in `lineItems` for `Braintree_Transaction::sale()`, as it is an array.
The way I got around this was to make `$lineItems` an array and then use `array_push` to push a new array for each `$product` into `$lineItems`

Full example ->

```
$basketProducts = $this->basket->all();

if($basketProducts){    
    $lineItems = array();   
foreach ($basketProducts as $product){
    array_push($lineItems, array(
        'quantity' => $product->quantity, 
        'name' => $product->title, 
        'kind' => 'debit', 
        'unitAmount' => $product->price, 
        'totalAmount' => $product->price * $product->quantity,
        'productCode' => $product->id)
    );
}
}

$sale = array(
    'orderId' => $hash,
    'amount' => $this->basket->subTotal() + $this->basket->delivery(),
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $request->getParam('payment_method_nonce'),
    'shippingAmount' => $this->basket->delivery(),
    'discountAmount' => '0',
    'shipsFromPostalCode' => '7008',
    'taxExempt' => true,
    'purchaseOrderNumber' => $hash1,
    'options' => array(
        'submitForSettlement' => true,
    ),
    'customer' => array(
        'firstName' => $request->getParam('name'),
        'email' => $request->getParam('email'),
    ),
    'shipping' => array(
        'firstName' => $request->getParam('name'),
        'streetAddress' => $request->getParam('address1'),
        'locality' => $request->getParam('city'),
        'postalCode' => $request->getParam('postal_code'),
        'countryCodeAlpha3' => 'AUS',
    ),
    'lineItems' => $lineItems
);

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale($sale);
```